# React Native Firebase Cloud Messaging throwing errors on build for RN 0.63.4

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the instructions for iOS from [here](https://rnfirebase.io/) but the compilation is showing these errors. I'm guessing it's some sort of version incompatibility, but I believe I'm on the latest version of `react-native-firebase`. When I build the app, these errors show up:

```
❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:91:51: expected a type

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(nonnull FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                              ^



❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:99:28: expected a type

didReceiveMessage:(nonnull FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                                  ^



❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:278:50: expected a type

- (NSDictionary*)parseFIRMessagingRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                           ^



❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:44:30: property 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging *'

    [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = YES;
                                                 ^



❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:223:31: no visible @interface for 'FIRMessaging' declares the selector 'sendMessage:to:withMessageID:timeToLive:'

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] sendMessage:data to:to withMessageID:messageId timeToLive:[ttl intValue]];
                             ^



❌  /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m:279:43: property 'appData' not found on object of type '__strong id'

    NSDictionary *appData = remoteMessage.appData;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the build failed:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening trustline.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination id=2811E5D0-88A1-490E-AB1C-2F192015AFB2

...

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gpcpfeonrmwlebbsoklspvmumvzd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseFirestore.o /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/firestore/RNFirebaseFirestore.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gpcpfeonrmwlebbsoklspvmumvzd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseMessaging.o /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

In my `package.json`:

```
...
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.8.1",
...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: are you using Expo or Reactnative cli because the downloading procedure of firebase is different for both first please tell which kind of cli are you using?

Comment: I am using expo @Abhishekkholiya

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem.

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase

> ⚠ The Hermes VM availble with react-native 0.60.3 and higher is not currectly supported. Some initial testing has been done and it appears that valid code in this library does not function correctly with Hermes.

I removed this package and it worked, as it seems to be separate from `@react-native-firebase/` scoped packages.

Comment: which package did you remove ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing exactly same errors.

Comment: @DjaferAbdelhadi I removed the unscoped react-native-firebase. Sorry for the delay, but I think this might help clarify the answer for other people.

Comment: Yes @charlie2. Please see the latest comments on the question and this answer for further details.